# Existing solution to share database data usefully but safely?

Tags: database, security

I want to share a db of information (eg, geonames.db.94y.info, a 
custom version of the geonames db) usefully, but safely. Is there a 
good way to do this?:

- People shouldn't be forced to download the db to get useful information.
- My current solution is to allow arbitrary SELECT queries with a 
  max CPU time of 5s.
- SELECT queries let you get SOME useful information, like the 
  world's 50 most populated "cities", and the total population in all 
  of the world's cities:

http://7cdf2e8dd01ab370c96c4d3daf67c5fb.geonames.db.94y.info/ 
http://d6da02fc16ae6e5afbf2a4c60b1e4e5c.geonames.db.94y.info/

- We see that the most populated city (Sao Paulo, 9839066) has about 
  1.19% of the world's urban population (829523357). We can even write 
  an (inefficient) query for this:

http://245bd4d07c2c5179dd37d8f7520ee7cf.geonames.db.94y.info/

- How about the top 2 cities combined? What percentage of the 
  world's urban population are they? Top 3 combined? Top n combined?
- For this and more complex examples, we need a PL, or perhaps 
  something more. While I'm OK w/ giving people readonly db access, 
  I'm not sure running arbitrary PL commands would be safe.
- Note: I realize MySQL can do "accumulative" queries like this, but:

  - It's not standard SQL
  - I'm using SQLite3
  - It requires multiple queries, but I only allow one query at a time
  - I'm sure there are examples that even MySQL couldn't handle.
- Basically, I want to let people get whatever info they want out of 
  the db w/o having to download it, provided they don't change the 
  data or eat up too much CPU time.

Is there a known solution here? I know about Drupal and other CMSs, 
but I don't think they can do this sort of thing?

[Note: I'm using geonames.db as an example, but it's in testing, so 
don't rely on the data/results]

Comment: As a general rule you should validate any input from a user before running a query against your database.  Off the top of my head without parsing the input queries I don't think you want to allow arbitrary queries unless your users are all trusted (e.g. all admins for example), but that's still a security violation.

Comment: Well, I only allow SELECT queries and only accept certain characters in the query. I agree allowing arbitrary SELECT queries isn't ideal, but the sad part is that it's not even sufficient. I'm trading security for convenience and failing at both.