# How does data.stackexchange.com allow queries securely?

Tags: sql-injection, dataexplorer

https://data.stackexchange.com/ lets me query some (all?) of 
stackexchange's data/tables using arbitrary SQL queries, including 
parametrization.

What program do they use to do this and is it published?

I want to create something like this myself (different data), but am 
constantly worried that I'll miss an injection attack or set 
permissions incorrectly.

Obviously, data.stackexchange.com has figured out how to do this 
securely. How do I replicate what they've done?

This follows up my earlier question: [Existing solution to share database data usefully but safely?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4707532/existing-solution-to-share-database-data-usefully-but-safely)

Comment: If you're using Windows, you can expose your data with ODATA (Microsoft WCF) and set filters to dynamically alter or throttle inbound queries.

Comment: data.stackexchange.com software is open source. Have a look https://code.google.com/p/stack-exchange-data-explorer/

Comment: @Adnan Thanks! That's exactly the info I needed. Could you turn that into an answer so I can approve it?

Comment: @barrycarter I'd love to, but I wouldn't feel so good about the rep I'll earn from it.

Comment: @Adnan: Then make it a community wiki.

Comment: @barrycarter if you have found more information on this topic you cuold add a answer on your own and accept it - I would like to read more about the topic.

Comment: @Daniel Nothing above what the google code already has. The basics appear to be 1) create READONLY users (and, even then, be careful with what access you GRANT), 2) prevent injection attacks. My current efforts/notes (not very good): https://github.com/barrycarter/bcapps/blob/master/bc-run-mysql-query.pl The SQLite3 version which works fine (because you can make the entire db read only since it's a single file): https://github.com/barrycarter/bcapps/blob/master/bc-run-sqlite3-query2.pl